# how to execute celery tasks conditionally python

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am new to celery.  I have a celery task that needs to be executed when a condition is met.  Otherwise retry after few minutes.  From the below code, I am stuck at how to retry the same task in else condition?  Appreciate your help.

```
@app.task(bind=True,soft_time_limit=4 * 3600)
def task_message_queue(id, name=None, tid=None, src=None, dest=None, queue="MessageQueue"):
   ThreadLocalStore().set_data({"id": id, "tid": tid, "name": name,"src": src, "dest":dest})
   num_files = os.popen("find %s -type f | wc -l" % dest).read().strip().split('\n')[0]
   if num_files < 20:
     #Move files from src to destination
   else:
     #wait for 2 minutes and retry the task
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `retry` to make celery retry the task and you can set the countdown so celery will wait for that much time and retry the task. Below is the code borrowed from official [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#id9). Modify the `@task`
 decorator according to your needs and also `self.retry`

```
from celery.task import task
@app.task(bind=True,soft_time_limit=4 * 3600)
def task_message_queue(self, id, name=None, tid=None, src=None, dest=None, queue="MessageQueue"):
   ThreadLocalStore().set_data({"id": id, "tid": tid, "name": name,"src": src, "dest":dest})
   num_files = os.popen("find %s -type f | wc -l" % dest).read().strip().split('\n')[0]
   try:
       if num_files < 20:
           #Move files from src to destination
       else:
           raise SOME_EXCEPTION
           #wait for 2 minutes and retry the task
   except SOME_EXCEPTION as exc:
       self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=TIME_TO_WAIT_BEFORE_RETRY)
```

Comment: Thanks Arpit.  So, I added a "raise" in else condition. and self.retry in inside the exception.  I will test it out.

Comment: Well actually you don't need a raise condition, if else works here

Comment: if i don't raise the exception, then "exc" is not defined.  i also had problem even when i raise exception, because exc doesn't get the actual task to execute

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on retry you could also just trigger the task again.

```
from celery.task import task
@app.task(bind=True,soft_time_limit=4 * 3600)
def task_message_queue(self, id, name=None, tid=None, src=None, dest=None, queue="MessageQueue"):
   ThreadLocalStore().set_data({"id": id, "tid": tid, "name": name,"src": src, "dest":dest})
   num_files = os.popen("find %s -type f | wc -l" % dest).read().strip().split('\n')[0]

   if num_files < 20:
       #Move files from src to destination
   else:
       # Trigger the task again in 120 seconds.
       task_message_queue.apply_async(countdown=120)
```